# jQuery Template Plugin or custom functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic-data

What I've got are chunks of code that are used over and over again in HTML. For example:

```
<div class="row">
    <span class="label"></span>
    <span class="control">
        <!-- content here -->
    </span>
</div>
```

Here we have a simple row that I use in forms. Naturally, this chunk of code happens over and over, page after page. I'm essentially writing this out with jQuery for my dynamic content.

Now, I ran across jQuery Templates and thought for a moment that this was my solution. However, the fact that you have to declare your templates within a script block WITHIN your .htm page... not good. I want total separation.

So what I'm asking is: what is the best way to accomplish essentially the same thing as a template but with a custom function or class? Or is this even necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your templates as separate html files that are loaded asynchronously (which you can set cache headers on appropriately), [here's how to do it](http://encosia.com/2010/10/05/using-external-templates-with-jquery-templates/).

Answer (score 0):

You could try to apply my solution: http://github.com/mpapis/jquery-pure-templates

I'm also interested in extending it for other uses if you are interested.

Comment: please not that your 4 near-identical answers have been flagged (by the community) as spammy; posting the same / similar answer runs the gauntlet of being seen as "astroturfing", especially if you don't declare an affiliation to the thing you are touting.